How to create a new operator '=??' for field bindings in F#?
I think this is simple, but I can't get it.
I wish to create a new operator, e.g. (=??) , that can be used like '=' for property field bindings.
That is the new operator will be used like:
MyProperty =?? NewValue

I would like the (=??) operator to do an Option.get NewValue so as to either return a value to MyProperty or immediately crash if NewValue has option none.
Can this be done in F# ??
Thank you for your consideration.
Addendum:
I still can't get this right. For example:
Assume a record called patient initialized as:
{Patient.RefId = Guid.NewGuid(); PatientAccountId = m.PatientAccountId; LastName = m.LastName; FirstName = m.FirstName; Mi = m.Mi; 
                 BirthDate = m.BirthDate}

Now that Patient record defines Birthdate as a string, but m.Birthdate is string option, so the assignment:
BirthDate = m.BirthDate 

fails.
But if I do BirthDate = Option.get m.BirthDate
all is good.
So how would I define an operator, e.g. =??, that does:
BirthDate = Option.get m.BirthDate`

as
BirthDate =?? m.BirthDate

TIA
Short Answer: No.

Note, in general, = does not imply assignment anywhere in F# - it's about comparison; the proposed name would hence be quite jarring for anyone past the initial learning phase in F# to read

If you disagree with my NOTE and believe you do actually have a use case where this is a big win, it may be worth extending your question with a broader example as to how you envisage using such a mechanism (its not impossible that it could be fleshed out into a fslang suggestion if it made sense, but as it stands, it doesn't feel like you have such an issue?)

@RubenBartelink I'm not disagreeing, just trying to understand how it can be done. ( I am new to operator overloads). Please see my addendum as to how I would like to use it. Thanks.

@RubenBartelink Also, I just randomly chose =??, it really does not matter what its called. :)

Let me try to rephrase the answer, perhaps this helps. The = in record initialization is not an operator, but a syntax element. So you cannot overload it. I think the best you can do is {... ; BirthDate = m.BirthDate.Value}

The <- assignment operator is not something you can replace - operators are generally functions that compute values - there is no equivalent of C/C++ overloading of assignment operators with the ability to demand an argument be implicitly passed by reference etc. NOTE
So the best syntax you'll get is:
MyProperty <- NewValue.Value

Which is functionally identical to:
MyProperty <- Option.get NewValue


It's worth noting that if you're constructing a new object, you can also initialize properties as part of the creation, i.e.
let myThing = Thing(args)
myThing.MyProperty <- NewValue.Value

Can be collapsed to:
let myThing = Thing(args, MyProperty = NewValue)


NOTE there are actually various ways to have a reference passed to a function (look for the & type signature symbol, including doing so implicitly IIRC). So it is actually technically possible to approximate it. However, I'd strongly recommend against doing so for normal usage, as it makes code really hard to scan to fish out where mutation is happening. The fact that mutable, <-, and Interlocked.Xyz(&thing, ...) are the only places that mutation can happen is a major feature of the language.

I was a little to vague I think. I would like the new function to compile without error and only crash when actually executed. e.g, MyProperty =??? NewValue compiles without error. But when executed, the =??? throws an error at runtime when NewValue is none. Thanks.

See also note on OP; the = in an initialization is not overridable in this way. Value/Option.get will both throw. You can do implicit conversion extensions, but that would be a nightmare. You could define a unary operator and then do = op X (with a spae in between) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading#remarks (but it's going to end up pretty ugly). The other problem is if you've got more than one of these in a block of code, you'll have a hard time telling which null check fired (which is why pattern matching is recommended)

operators are generally functions that don't take rvalues –> I'm confused, do you mean lvalues instead?

apologies re lvalue/rvalue mixup - I stopped using C++ in 03 and yes I do mean lvalue. Off to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues for penance ;)
